# Query with join query, need assistance

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have three tables.

I combine the company and component tables with this code

```
$questions_query =  "SELECT company_mast.id, component_mast.component_id
                    FROM company_mast
                    LEFT JOIN component_mast 
                    ON company_mast.id = component_mast.company_id
                    WHERE component_mast.component_name = '".$component_name."'
                    AND company_mast.company_name = '".$company_name."'";
```

The result is as desired, If I put company_name as Bells and component_name as Assets I get and id of 3 for Bells and an id of 9 for Assets. Now if you look at the customfields table I need to pull all the questions with the a specific company_id and component_id.

Example: If the user enters Bells and Assets they need to receive all questions with the company_id of 3 and the component_id of 9.

So this is my query

```
SELECT *
FROM customfield_mast
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT company_mast.id, component_mast.component_id
            FROM company_mast
            LEFT JOIN component_mast
            ON company_mast.id = component_mast.company_id
            WHERE component_mast.component_name = 'Assets'
            AND company_mast.company_name = 'Bells')
att
ON customfield_mast.company_id = customfield_mast.component_id
```

This however returns all questions in my db, which is not what I want. I'm positive my last "ON" statement is the problem, however I don't know what the correct statement would be. I have not started with `SQL` injection protection, this is grass roots to get my queries to work. Thanks for the help

Comment: It would be much easier if you posted the create table commands and some insert statements, rather than using an image. Or even better create a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with a working model

Comment: use `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`? P.S. your question is still vague though. in simpler terms, write what you want.

Comment: Problem is that images are blocked for many employees making your audience shrink. If you posted the actual create table/inserts then you will have more eyes reviewing the question. Also, I am not saying you didn't do your homework in posting the question, I am offering suggestions on improving it.

Comment: Alright I'll post them both, so my question is widely accepted by all. PS, I know, i was just messing with you =)

Comment: @IrishWhiskey It would be much appreciated if you realized the work it's going to take to give you a 100% free answer to solve your problem and not be rude to the people who are volunteering their time to help you. Thanks!

Comment: @IrishWhiskey well thanks for the work that went into it. unfortunately, it's not easier to answer a question where we type out the simulated data. please note that "easier" != "possible." sure, it's possible for folks to go through the data entry process for you but then, this is a volunteer site and we're just here to help. if you reduce the barriers to answer, then you're going to get a better answer faster. so have it your way ... formatting the question easily, or getting a great answer quickly.

Comment: Did not mean to make this into a flame thread, jeez. It was just a simple comment. I deleted the comment. I am editing as suggested. This is not a war.

Comment: @IrishWhiskey That's fine it's not very easy to detect sarcasm over this sort of forum.

Comment: @Zane it's not a problem. I like humor, I forgot text on a volunteer site is not the best place to display my sarcastic humor. =)

Comment: If only there were a tag you could place on your comments for sarcasm. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's wrong with another join?

```
SELECT company_mast.id, component_mast.component_id, CFM.DisplayName
FROM company_mast
LEFT JOIN component_mast 
  ON company_mast.id = component_mast.company_id
LEFT JOIN CustomField_mast CFM
  ON CFM.Company_ID = Component_mast.Company_ID 
  and  CFM.Component_ID = component_Mast.Component_ID
WHERE component_mast.component_name = '".$component_name."'
  AND company_mast.company_name = '".$company_name."'";
```

Comment: nothing wrong with it. I just didn't think of it. Thanks, I'll check it out.

Comment: It worked, I changed "CFM.DisplayName" to "CFM.*". Do you see any problems with that? It's returning what I want.

Comment: if new columns are added or removed later than * will drop or pick those up.  By explicitly defining field names you get what you want no more, no less; and modest performance gains occur.  * is just not good form long term.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `customfield_mast`  
WHERE `company_id` =
     (SELECT `id` FROM `company_mast` WHERE `company_name` = '$company_name')
AND `component_id` IN 
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`component_id`) FROM `component_mast` 
    WHERE `component_name` = '$component_name')
```

Comment: looks clean, I like it. However I get this message 'Subquery returns more than 1 row'

Comment: means you have reduandant entries in your database. isn't your company name or component name unique?

Comment: company name is, component name is not. Component name will have the same 4 values for each company. The component_id is unique